# What type of security should I use in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-security, spring-rest

I'm writing the back end for a web app in Spring.  It uses Rest to communicate with the front end.  The front end is browser based, so it can't contain a private key.
I've been trying to figure out what type of security I need to meet the following conditions:

1) The user logs in and I create a token that corresponds to a user object

2) I reply to the login request with this token

3) the token is attached by the front end to every request that I get so that I know what user is making that request.

Whenever I read up on Spring security I find two things, which are oauth2 and basic authentication, which I keep seeing people say is insecure.  It seems like I can accomplish what I want with oath2, but it gets really confusing when I actually try to implement it.

What I want seems simple enough that I could just do all the work myself, but that seems like a terrible idea, since I have no experience with security. Could I, for example, have a local map of authentication tokens to user objects and redirect any request that has an invalid token to a login page?  Taking into account repeated invalid request and expiry of tokens over time.

Or would I be missing a bunch of important security features by doing this?  What specific words can I research to answer some of these questions on my own?

Comment: [This question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/988/is-basic-auth-secure-if-done-over-https) seems to suggest that basic auth over HTTPS is "ok". It's much simpler than OAuth2 to implement, and that alone must increase it's security - well written basic auth > poorly written OAuth2. FWIW, I would use basic auth over HTTPS.

Comment: Basic authentication doesn't support your criteria since it is basically a base64 encoding of the username and password.


OAuth2 is useful when the resource server (your rest service, for example), doesn't want to take credentials, but instead wants to off-load that effort somewhere else (say, an authorization server).

It sounds like what you've created with your token-based approach is a session.